# Too many erros after upgrading TeX

Tags: installing

I am getting too many errors since I upgraded my computer with the latest 
version of TeX. For instance, the following piece of code doesn't work any more.
Could you help me do a clean install and \ or make the following piece of code work again? I am using the TeXworks editor and I run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}

\newcommand{\greek}[1]{{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}#1}}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

Protagoras (\greek{Πρωταγόρας}) says that ``Man is the measure of all things''
(\greek{Ἄνθρωπος μέτρον}), meaning that there is no objective truth. One
opinion can be better than another, but it cannot be \emph{truer}.

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I attached the [.log](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5301947/untitled-1.log) file.

Comment: I get no error from that input.

Comment: That example works fine for me.  You should post the `.log` (and put `\listfiles` in the preamble of the document).

Comment: @jon I attached the .log file as you suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately the `.log` file cuts off before the end, and before any error messages are given.

Comment: @jon So, what does this mean based on your experience? How could I fix the problem anyway? What to try next?

Comment: I mean: you need to post the full `.log` file.  The part you posted does not provide any clues as to what is going on.  (And please add `\listfiles` to the preamble of your test document.)

Comment: I did exactly what you asked me to do. Now I get the error: ! Undefined control sequence.

Comment: @eualin if you attached the full log something went wrong with the upload. If you follow the `.log` link in your question you will see that the link ends before the end of the file in fact it ends part way through the word `Font`. It shows no error message of any sort which must be later in the file.

Comment: using a default 2012 setup I get `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \textPi ` on that input.

Comment: The error with `\textPi` is due to `utf8` instead of `utf8x`.

Comment: Is this coming from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71541/latex-error-file-adjustbox-sty-not-found  as suggested in comments there? If yes, please flag it for closure/deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the error

```
 ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \textPi
```

searching this site for `\textPi` lead to a answer that suggested adding

```
\usepackage{textalpha}
```

then it appears to work for me.

---

Note @egreg commented that your unchanged example worked for him. I suspect it should work unchanged. I think that there have been some updates to the Greek support since TL2012 was released so an alternative might be to use the texlive update script to update all relevant packages.

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much for helping me sort this bug out.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `utf8` as option for `inputenx`, then you can't use directly Greek characters; for this you should add

```
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
```

to your preamble. Otherwise, use `utf8x`, which however is not compatible with `biblatex`.

Comment: I don't really need \usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}.  It works fine with both \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and \usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}. But which one to choose?

Comment: @eualin With `LGRx` and `utf8` (without `textalpha`) you're ready for using also `biblatex`.